# Get a property from a cypher queried relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query:

```
Match (:Company{value:{value}})<-[partOf:PART_OF*]-(per:Person)
-[:MEMBER_OF]->(group:Social) 
Return {Group: {name:group.name, nodeId:group.nodeId, tags:labels(group), 
        people:collect({name:per.name, nodeId:per.nodeId, tags:labels(per)})}}
```

I want to retrieve a specific property from ‘partOf' Is that possible ? Or do I use something like path and get the relationship and it's property in each passing?

Thank you, very much

EDIT: With Chris's comment in mind, what if I use '*..2' that's not much of data and I want to retrieve properties from those relationships?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query using `-[:PART_OF*]-` it will match an *unlimited* chain of relationships (and intervening nodes) of the type `:PART_OF`. This is caused by the `*`. So the identifier `partOf` does not refer to a single relationship, but rather to an entire collection of them.

Thus you can't get a specific property from `partOf`, as it's a collection and not a thing with properties (a single node or relationship).

Note: you almost *never* want to use '*' like that, as it can very easily match huge amounts of data in your graph.

---

If you want to get properties off elements in the `partOf` collection, you could try one of these approaches:

- Pick an offset, e.g. `partOf[0].prop`, `partOf[1].prop`, etc
- Aggregate the properties you're interested in - perhaps into a collection of their own, e.g. `[r IN partOf | r.prop]` (now you have a new collection containing the property values from each relationship). Or maybe sum them (assuming they're a number), e.g. `reduce(acc=0, r IN partOf | acc + r.prop)`.

Comment: Hey Chris, I understand it's not efficient but I have a requirement to do something like this.. :).

Comment: Ok. This answer is correct though, right? You can't get properties from a collection. I'll edit and add in details on extracting from within the collection...